# Gulp.src is not creating a new file in destination

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gulp, xampp

I am using local xammp for my wordpress Website. I think gulp.src is not creating a new file in destination.

var gulp = require('gulp');

```js
gulp.task('styles',function (){
  return gulp.src('./FictionalUniversity/wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/front-page.php')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./FictionalUniversity/wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/css/'))
});
```

Comment: It is in polish, however there are a lot of source codes, so you may compare it to your code - [gulp styles](https://wpkurs.pl/gulp/).

Comment: Do you have errors, or the file is not just creating?

Comment: i am not getting any error, it just not creating.